# How to learn HP Exstream

Tags: opentext, hp-exstream

I am planning on learning HP Exstream. What are the prerequisite for learning HP Exstream. 
What language is it in. Please share any materials.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pay for the courses just like everyone else.

There is little to nothing online. If you contact the vendor, you can arrange for training. As for the programming language, it is similar to VB except when it's not. That's really the best advice I can give you.

The syntax works exactly like VB, but it has almost none of the intrinsic functions. Those are provided in one of the HP Exstream Training Manuals.

Answer (score 0):

Exstream Version 9 and less have the capabilities to shell out into windows and call any program you desire via its compiled .PUB file. The PUB file contains everything on a documents page/s or template of pages which also can house any variable driven tables columns rows cells or text boxes or actual letters words or phrases if in effect if-then-else include or exclude ro call a subroutine or function. Pages can flow, tables can grow and flow as well as text that may populate a string or integer variable, That text being an XML element, flat ascii line by line file or ebcdic line mode also known as Columnar records whereas each record is a customer record that gets turned into an invoice, bill, statement or letter, i.e. CCM Customer Communication Management & Correspondences.

Version 16, Beginning with the OpenText Acquire of Exstream Suite products from HP and their so called first release of the product Hence buying it all from HP in 2016. Can do this as well v16+.